# Flask-login is able to log in user, but still AnonymousUserMixin for all subsequent requests

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am able to successfully login and authenticate the user and I can access their info with `current_user` from the login method. But then when I make another API call and try to access `current_user`, I get an error and `current_user` is of type `AnonymousUserMixin`.

I thought the issue may be with the `load_user` function, so I added a print statement but it seems as though it never gets called.

Is there anything wrong with the below setup that would prevent `load_user` from getting executed when an API call is made or cause the user's session to not persist?

```
# app.py
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    print("[LoadUser]")
    return Users.query.get(user_id)

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    user = Users(
        id = unique_id, name=users_name, email=users_email
    )
    login_user(user, remember=True)
    print(current_user.username) # Works with no issue
    return

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    print(current_user.username) # AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'username'
```

Comment: I am encountering the same problem. Did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your test route does not protect against anonymous access. according to flask-login docs 0.7..current_user would then be anonymous... Which means if you lock the test route to logged in users only current_user will then be populated!

```py
@app.route("/test")
@login_required
def test():
    print(current_user.username)
```

[https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mImWy.png)